# StreamAPI java filter

Tags: java, java-stream

Привет) У меня есть стрим с публикациями, сам класс публикации выглядит так:

```
public class Article {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private ArticleStatus status;
    private Long authorId;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
    private List<Tag> tags;
}

----------

public class Tag {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

И есть стрим с тегами в качестве входного параметра - простой `Stream<String>`

Мне необходимо отфильтровать стрим с публикациями по тегам (если он содержит хоть один перечисленный тег - отлично, подойдет). То есть, задействовать вместе  `Stream<Article> articles` и  `Stream<String> tags`

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: У меня дисонанс в голове с вашим наймингом. Пожалуйста добавьте ваш код который вы хотите отфильтровать

Comment: примерно так: `Stream<Articles> flteredArticles = articles.filter(a -> a.getTags.forEach(Tag::getName()) atLeast contains one tag from Stream<String> tags)`
Добавить, боюсь, больше нечего - это все что есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Tag> articlesTags1 = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    articlesTags1.add(new Tag().setName("tag1"));
    articlesTags1.add(new Tag().setName("tag2"));
    articlesTags1.add(new Tag().setName("tag3"));

    List<Tag> articlesTags2 = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    articlesTags2.add(new Tag().setName("tag2"));
    articlesTags2.add(new Tag().setName("tag3"));
    articlesTags2.add(new Tag().setName("tag4"));

    List<Tag> articlesTags3 = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    articlesTags3.add(new Tag().setName("tag5"));
    articlesTags3.add(new Tag().setName("tag6"));
    articlesTags3.add(new Tag().setName("tag7"));

    Stream<String> tags = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"tag1", "tag7"});
    List<String> tagsList = tags.collect(Collectors.toList());

    Stream<Articles> articles =
        Stream.of(
            new Articles[] {
              new Articles().setTitle("title1").setTags(articlesTags1),
              new Articles().setTitle("title2").setTags(articlesTags2),
              new Articles().setTitle("title3").setTags(articlesTags3)
            });

    Stream<Articles> flteredArticles =
        articles.filter(
            a ->
                a.getTags().stream()
                    .anyMatch(
                        tag ->
                            tagsList.stream()
                                .anyMatch(searchingTag -> searchingTag.equals(tag.getName()))));

    flteredArticles.forEach(article -> System.out.println(article.getTitle()));
    
  }
```

Поменяйте классы на такие

Tag.java

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

public class Tag {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Articles> articles;

  /** @return the id */
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  /** @param id the id to set */
  public Tag setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the name */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /** @param name the name to set */
  public Tag setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the articles */
  public List<Articles> getArticles() {
    return articles;
  }

  /** @param articles the articles to set */
  public Tag setArticles(List<Articles> articles) {
    this.articles = articles;
    return this;
  }
}
```

и Articles.java

```
package test;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Articles {
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private String text;
  private String status;
  private Long authorId;
  private Date createdAt;
  private Date updatedAt;
  private List<Tag> tags;

  /** @return the id */
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  /** @param id the id to set */
  public Articles setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the title */
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  /** @param title the title to set */
  public Articles setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the text */
  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  /** @param text the text to set */
  public Articles setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the status */
  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  /** @param status the status to set */
  public Articles setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the authorId */
  public Long getAuthorId() {
    return authorId;
  }

  /** @param authorId the authorId to set */
  public Articles setAuthorId(Long authorId) {
    this.authorId = authorId;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the createdAt */
  public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
  }

  /** @param createdAt the createdAt to set */
  public Articles setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the updatedAt */
  public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
  }

  /** @param updatedAt the updatedAt to set */
  public Articles setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    return this;
  }

  /** @return the tags */
  public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
  }

  /** @param tags the tags to set */
  public Articles setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Это прекрасно))

Там ломбок с: 

Я просто лишние аннотации поудаляла. Большое спасибо!!

Comment: @Anastasiya Да конечно. Я на чистом Java решил сделать рабочий пример чтоб не было вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

Вы слишком путано формулируете вопрос. Если я вас правильно понял, то есть какое-то количество публикаций с вложенными тегами, а также есть стринговый список названий тегов. Нужно отфильтровать те публикации, в которых вложнные теги совпадают по имени (поле name) со стринговым списком тегов.

Во-первых, если вы решаете такую задачу, то вы уже на неправильном пути. Такие операции должны быть возложены на бд (причем оптимизировать поиск в бд довольно просто - его можно свести исключительно к поиску по первичным ключам). Почему так? Представьте, что у вас миллионы публикация и не меньшее количество тегов. Вы все загрузите в память и будете итерироваться? Тогда вам никакой памяти не хватит. Подумайте над этим...

Что касается решения задачи (чисто теоретически), я бы добавил простой метод в Article. Так код будет лучше читаться в отличии от стрима в стриме. Ну и для списка стринговых тегов я бы все таки использовал сет, а не другую коллекцию.

```
    public class Article {
        
        private Long id;
        private String title;
        private String text;
        //private ArticleStatus status;
        private Long authorId;
        private Date createdAt;
        private Date updatedAt;
        private List<Tag> tags;
        
        public boolean contain(Set<String> tags) {
            return this.tags.stream().anyMatch(tag -> tags.contains(tag.getName()));
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Tag {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private List<Article> articles;
    }


public class Main {

    public List<Article> filter(List<Article> articles, Set<String> tags) {
        return articles.stream()
                .filter(art -> art.contain(tags))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Comment: А если в бд? у меня Spring JPA

Comment: @Anastasiya ну так отлично, так и должно быть))

Comment: @Anastasiya таблица публикаций к таблице тегов относится как многие ко многим. по сути вам достаточно убрать у таблицы тегов автогенерируемый айдишник, и сделать айдишником имя тега (стринговое). любая реляционнаябаза данных это умеет. а дальше вы просто по имени тега ищите тег в таблице тегов, а потом по связи вытягиваете публикации. быстро , дешево и сердито))

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<Article> arts /* = Stream.of(new Article()) */;
Stream<String> tags /* = Stream.of("what", "ever") */;
```

стрим можно проходить только один раз, поэтому тэги придется собрать в коллекцию

```
Set<String> tagNames = tags.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

тогда фильтр будет выглядеть как то так:

```
arts.filter(a -> a.tags.stream()
            .map(t -> t.name)
            .anyMatch(n -> tagNames.contains(n)));
```